What are the stationary distributions of this Markov Chain?
The Transition Matrix of the chain is : $$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1/3 & 2/3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
2/3 & 0 & 1/3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1/3 & 0 & 2/3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
0 & 0 & 1/3 & 0 & 2/3 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \\   
0 & 0 & 0 & 1/2 & 0 & 1/4& 1/4 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1/2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1/2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1/2 & 1/2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\\end{bmatrix}
$$
To solve the problem I used the formula : $π$ = $Pπ$, and I found the following :
$π_1 = \frac23 π_2 + \frac13 π_3$
$π_2 = \frac13 π_1$
$π_3 = \frac23 π_1 + \frac13 π_2 + \frac23 π_3 + \frac13 π_4 $
$π_4 = \frac12 π_5 + \frac12 π_6 $
$π_5 = \frac23 π_4$
$π_6 = \frac14 π_5$
$π_7 = \frac14 π_5 + \frac12 π_7 + π_8 $
$π_8 = \frac12 π_6 + \frac12 π_7$
$π_1 + π_2 + π_3 + π_4 + π_5 + π_6 + π_7 + π_8 = 1$
The problem is that using this method I found : $π_4=0$
Does the fact that this Markov Chain has recurrent classes mean that I have to find the stationary distributions for the closed recurrent classes?
Thanks for the help!

$\pi_4=0$ is not an issue... state $4$ is just transient (as are 5 and 6). You will either end up in 1,2,3 or in 7,8, and the stationary distributions will be mixures of the stationary distributions for these submatrices (and when you solve the system there should be an extra degree of freedom to reflect that).

Should I find the stationary distributions for the closed classes? Thanks for the quick reply!

and a stationary measure satisfies $\pi P=\pi$

I mean, you should find the stationary distributions for this markov chain like the question says. But there will be a family of them expressible in terms of the stationary distributions for the submatrices for states (1,2,3) and (7,8). (I'm not sure what you're asking.)

There are two closed irreducible classes of this Markov chain, namely $C_1=\{1,2,3\}$ and $C_2=\{7,8\}$. You need to find the unique stationary distributions corresponding to $C_1$ and $C_2$.
Call them $\boldsymbol{\hat \pi_1}=(\hat \pi_{1y})_{y \in C_1}$ and $\boldsymbol{\hat \pi_2}=(\hat\pi_{2y})_{y \in C_2}$, found by solving $$\boldsymbol{\hat \pi_1}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1/3 & 2/3 \\
2/3 & 0 & 1/3 \\
1/3 & 0 & 2/3
\end{bmatrix}=\boldsymbol{\hat \pi_1}$$ and $$\boldsymbol{\hat \pi_2}
\begin{bmatrix}
1/2 & 1/2 \\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}=\boldsymbol{\hat \pi_2}.$$
Let $$\pi_{1y}=\begin{cases}\hat \pi_{1y} &,\text{ if }y\in C_1 \\ 0 &, \text{ if } y \notin C_1\end{cases}$$ and $$\pi_{2y}=\begin{cases}\hat \pi_{2y} &,\text{ if }y\in C_2 \\ 0 &, \text{ if } y \notin C_2\end{cases}.$$
Then $\boldsymbol\pi_1 =(\pi_{1y})$ and $\boldsymbol\pi_2=(\pi_{2y})$ are two distinct stationary distributions of the Markov chain. Therefore you have a set of stationary distributions, given by the convex combination of $\boldsymbol\pi_1$ and $\boldsymbol\pi_2$.
